# Slowcheeta not working for web applications in Teambuild

Tags: tfs, tfsbuild, slowcheetah, xdt-transform

I read this [article](http://sedodream.com/2011/12/12/SlowCheetahXMLTransformsFromACIServer.aspx) on getting slowcheeta working on the build server.  It works fine with Console apps but I can not get it to work for Web Applications.

I verified that the build service can access the slowcheeta (works fine for consoles apps).
I am able to transform on my local machine for web applications correctly as well.

The primary .config file is set to content do not copy, the transforms are set to none, do not copy.
The server is TFS 2012 with visual studio 2010 and 2012 installed to support build tasks.

[github](https://github.com/sayedihashimi/slow-cheetah/issues/30)

Comment: Why are you using slowcheeta for web apps? web.config transformations are supported out of the box, you don't need slowcheeta for that.

Comment: Try run a build with verbosity turned up high (right click a build -> queue, then look in the second tab for logging settings).

Comment: @frennky - It doesn't work out of the box with TeamBuild.  The transforms get applied as part of WebDeploy, not the build process.

Comment: I have the same issue as the OP.  Can't find the answer anywhere.